# Returning string in dynamically loaded DLL library fails

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pinvoke

I will completely describe you my problem and process. I was making an editor for an other's game and I have one wrapper DLL written in C language which I am communicating with.

At first I had list of methods with `DllImport` calling functions from the DLL. First method was `CSharp_new_CEditorInterface` which returned an `IntPtr`. Then `CSharp_CEditorInterface_CreateApp` which toke `ulong` handle to window control where it will draw graphics. At the end I should call `CSharp_CEditorInterface_CloseApp` and `CSharp_delete_CEditorInterface`. These methods take a `HandleRef` with pointer returned from `CSharp_new_CEditorInterface`.

However, I needed to call creating and deleting methods multiple times and when calling `CSharp_CEditorInterface_CreateApp` for the second time, it threw `System.AccessViolationException`. So I decided to load and unload DLL dynamically with LoadLibrary and FreeLibrary. I wrote an application that with reflection browsed all p/invoke methods and generated code consisting of delegates, readonly fields and GetProcAddress-es. However, as I found out, the entry points were only partial. `CSharp_new_CEditorInterface` was `_CSharp_new_CEditorInterface@0`. With my DLL export viewer, I saved all complete function names and then searched within. In constructor, I call `LoadLibrary` and appropriate function loads. In `Dispose`, there was `FreeLibrary`.

This solution worked fine, functions were called OK, until I discovered that some functions which return string are throwing `AccessViolationException`. They work fine when using `DllImport` method. I have also discovered that when calling ANY function from static class, thus loading another module, calling problematic functions is now OK and they return appropriate values. However, after unloading DLL dynamically and reloading, it does not work again and guess which exception is thrown.

Now which function I call and in what order:

```
--When initializing--
LoadLibrary(string)  (winapi)
--bunch of GetProcAddress, Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer--
new_CEditorInterface()  (from DLL)
CreateApp(HandleRef, ulong)  (from DLL)

--When closing in Dispose--
CloseApp(HandleRef)  (from DLL)
delete_CEditorInterface(HandleRef)  (from DLL)
FreeLibrary(IntPtr)  (winapi)
```

I should note that the DLL was not created to be loaded more than one at a time.

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: can you show some real code that you are actually using and point out where in the code where you are getting problem, this is a bit hard / long to follow showing code is usually easier for others to offer help verses sudo coding.. also look at Singleton and or how to create a Mutex for single instance running of code

Comment: I think I have described everything needed. Unmanaged method which returns string works OK when calling through DllImport, but fails when called through pointer from GetProcAddress. When loading specified DLL with DllImport, the method works fine, until unload and reload.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope that this helps you

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string libname);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

//Load
IntPtr Handle = LoadLibrary(fileName);
if (Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
{
     int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
     throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to load library (ErrorCode: {0})",errorCode));
}

//Free
if(Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
        FreeLibrary(Handle);
```

If you want to call functions first you must create delegeate that matches this function
and then use WinApi GetProcAddress

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName); 


IntPtr funcaddr = GetProcAddress(Handle,functionName);
YourFunctionDelegate function = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(funcaddr,typeof(YourFunctionDelegate )) as YourFunctionDelegate ;
function.Invoke(pass here your parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for effort, but I have all necessary delegates for functions. I have also checked that handle is not zero. I am sure. Other functions loaded the samy way work. Just those which return string. Maybe MarshalAs can somehow solve this?